# Maslov correction N-dimensional harmonic oscillator with different frequencies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, semiclassical

I am working on the semiclassical dynamics of a N-dimensional harmonic oscillator based on an autocorrelation function approach and I like to treat a system with independent oscillators, which have different frequencies. The Hamiltonian of a 2-dimensional model system in normal coordinate representation would be given as

$\hat{H}=\dfrac{\hat{p}^{2}_{1}}{2m_{1}}+\dfrac{\hat{p}^{2}_{2}}{2m_{2}}+\dfrac{m_{1}}{2}\omega^{2}_{1}q^{2}_{1}+\dfrac{m_{2}}{2}\omega^{2}_{2}q^{2}_{2}$,

with momentum operators $\hat{p}_{i}$, masses $m_{i}$, harmonic frequencies $\omega_{i}$ and normal coordinates $q_{i}$ where $i\in\{1,2\}$.

In one dimension, the Maslov correction was required to correct the autocorrelation function and now I like to understand how it works for multiple dimensions.

In N-dimensions, the Maslov correction is given by $e^{-iN\frac{\pi}{2}k}, N = 1,2,\dots$ as long as we consider a system with N identical harmonic frequencies $\omega_{1}=\omega_{2}=\dots=\omega_{N}$. However, it seems not obvious to me how to generalize the Maslov correction, when I consider a system with different frequencies $\omega_{1}\neq\omega_{2}\neq\dots\neq\omega_{N}$ (altough some of them might be identical).

Has anyone still considered this issue or is aware of literature dealing with this topic?

Comment: It seems OP is asking about non-coupled [SHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator)s. This is a completely separable system, i.e. the various dimensions don't talk to each other, i.e it is $N$ independent 1D problems. The system is only periodic if the $\omega$s are [commensurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(mathematics))

Comment: What do you mean by OP? Since I am interested in studying molecular vibrational dynamics, the different $\omega$ are presumably incommensurable. Will this kill the maslov Correction?

Comment: OP = Original Poster, in this case: you.